# usb issue, boot not completed; hw or sw issue?

Tags: linux-kernel

I can't realize whether I'm having a kernel or hardware issue...

clicking ctl-d the boot process doesn't come to its end.

any hint?

[image: Boot messages]

Comment: This also happens with invalid mount points in `/etc/fstab`. Removing the invalid entry makes booting normal. Here removing usb device and reboot should boot normally. Need an answer from people familiar with this issue.